# Strange behavior with VOLUME in a inherited image

Tags: docker

I've got 2 `Dockerfile`s.

Here is `a` :

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN mkdir /opt/test

RUN touch /opt/test/test.txt

VOLUME /opt/test
```

Here is `b` :

```
FROM a

RUN touch /opt/test/b.txt
```

Then I build both my images :

```
cd a && sudo docker build -t a . && cd ../b && sudo docker build -t b .
```

And I run `b` image :

```
sudo docker run -i --rm --name b -t b /bin/bash
```

In my `b` container I can't see `/opt/test/b.txt` normally by my `b` image :

```
root@4db094589f0d:/# ls /opt/test/
test.txt
```

If I remove `VOLUME /opt/test` from my `a` `Dockerfile`, then I will see correctly my `/opt/test/b.txt`.

Could someone explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

[Changes to a data volume will not be included when you update an image](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#volume-def)

You could use a script to create the file if its empty.

Comment: What's strange is if I have `ADD ./my-b-file.txt /opt/test/` in `b` `Dockerfile`, then `my-b-file.txt` is present when running `b` image. So is the real sentence should have been "changes to a data volume will not be included when you update an image **except for ADD instruction**" ?

Comment: @AnthonyO. Sounds more like a bug than a documentation issue. However, I could not reproduce; I got a `lchown /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/[long id]/opt/test/my-b-file.txt: not a directory` that caused the build to fail.